# Convert street address from string to columns - Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of 350 addresses in a single column excel file that I need to import to a SQL table, breaking the data into columns.

content of the Excel cells is such as this one

Courtesy Motors 2520 Cohasset Rd - Chico, CA 95973-1307 530-893-1300

What strategy should I apply to import this in a clean fashion?

I was thinking

NAME <- anything before the 1st digit

STREET ADDRESS <- from the 1st digit to the '-'

STATE <- Anything from the last ',' to the '-' immediately before  (the address field can contain some - )

TELEPHONE <- Last 12 char

ZIP <- 10 first char of the last 22 char

I work in `C#` if this matters.

Is RegEx the appropriate approach? I'm not too familiar with them, so I'm not sure.  Can somebody suggest a RegEx expression that would do the job (or part of it)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should pull out each part in a capture group:

```
(\D+) ([^-]+) - ([^,]+, \w+) ([\d-]+) ([\d-]+)
```

Capture groups, in order:

1. Name
2. Street address
3. City, State
4. Zip
5. Phone

Comment: The OP didn't specify City, just State.

Comment: Right, Jason; but it should be fairly straightforward to adapt the capture to only grab the state instead. I figured I'd provide a more general regex that could be adapted.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression is the tool for this job. I am not a C# developer, so I can't give you the exact code. Nonetheless, the following regex should work. Most IDEs have this built in or if you have access to UNIX `sed` would work.

```
([^\d]+)\s(.+?)\s-\s[^,]+,\s([A-Z]{2})\s([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)
```

Captures:

1. Name
2. Address
3. State
4. ZIP
5. Phone

Comment: It's much simpler to write `[^\d]` as just `\D`.

Comment: @Amber, some regex implementations don't support negation groups.

Comment: @Amber, fair. There's 100 ways to write regexes, that's the beauty and the curse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google geocode API. You might have to remove phone number from there, but if someone is looking for address parsing with more functionality than just regex - they can even get lat/long for address.

For your address example

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=2520%20Cohasset%20Rd%20-%20Chico%2C%20CA%2095973-1307%20530-893-1300%20%20&sensor=false

Documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/